# Command to search a file based on the input in the other file

Tags: perl, shell, grep, command

I am on Linux platform and I would need help with the command that will accomplish my task or any suggestion on how to accomplish this.

I have 2 text files, the first file has a list of ID's (Log ID ) and the second file is a log file that has entries of various activities with Log ID.

Basically, I would like to pick a log id from the first file and search if this log id is present in the second file.

The first file has 15000 Log Id's and manually it wouldn't be possible to check each.

Here is my coding attempt:
`grep -q "LogID: 1005534" logfile.txt && echo "yes" || echo "no"`

But how to iterate the command with all the log-id's I have?

Here is the logID and actual log file

[image] [image]

Comment: I got the below command `grep -q "LogID: 1005534" logfile.txt && echo "yes" || echo "no"`. But how to iterate the command it with all the log-id's I have.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a place where you can ask others for help to get your program working if you have encountered a *specific problem*. For us to do that you need to have written a program. It is expected that you at least make an effort rather than just dumping your requirement here and waiting for a solution to pop out.

Comment: Please provide your textual information as text in the question, not as a picture.

Comment: @Borodin You know there **is** a (quite decent) coding attempt. Just in the comment, not in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your own attempt, using grep, is quite close.
Based on the two files quoted at the end of this answer as demo
(a MCVE by you would have been nice...), I propose to make three lists, using:

- positive: `grep -of Ids.txt Logfile.txt | sort -u`
- negative a: `grep -vf Ids.txt Logfile.txt | grep -o "LogID: .*" | sort -u`
- negative b: `grep -o "LogID: .*" Logfile.txt >InIDs.txt && grep -vf InIDs.txt IDs.txt | sort -u`

Note:

- If you system has two "sort" programs, e.g. Windows and GNU, make sure to use the GNU version, i.e. by giving full path to binary; windows sort does not know `-u` option.
- These files have **UNIX line endings** (only LF, not CRLF), that is important.
- Assumption: The string "LogID: dddddd" only occurs at the end of lines
  (this assumption can be slightly relaxed, maybe removed, with more sophisticated regexes)

Environment IDs.txt
(note the 1005539, 1005540 **not** contained in Logfile.txt):

```
LogID: 1005534
LogID: 1005535
LogID: 1005536
LogID: 1005537
LogID: 1005538
LogID: 1005539
LogID: 1005540
```

Environment Logfile.txt
(note the 1005548 **not** contained in IDs.txt and the lines with identical ID):

```
blabla LogID: 1005534
bloblo LogID: 1005536
blaablaa LogID: 1005534
blublu LogID: 1005537
blibli LogID: 1005548
bluubluu LogID: 1005537
bleble LogID: 1005538
```

Output, positive:

```
LogID: 1005534
LogID: 1005536
LogID: 1005537
LogID: 1005538
```

Output, negative a
(those which are in Logfile.txt but not in IDs.txt):

```
LogID: 1005548
```

Output, negative b
(those which are in IDs.txt but not in Logfile.txt):

```
LogID: 1005535
LogID: 1005539
LogID: 1005540
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Get unique IDs fr file1. For each ID, search it in file2

```
sort -u file1 | while read ID; do
  grep -q $ID file2 && echo $ID: YES || echo $ID: no # costly operation & repetitive
done
```

2: If you have lots of entries (particularly on file2). Uniquely, obtain all IDs from the two files and compare notes

```
sort -u file1 > /tmp/f1
grep -i target.*logID file2 |sed 's/.*target://' |sort -u > /tmp/f2 # one-pass
diff -y /tmp/f1 /tmp/f2 | grep -q ">" # YES list
diff -y /tmp/f1 /tmp/f2 | grep ">" # no list
```

Comment: Respect, nice alternative way of going about this.